# How can I keep running?

Tags: the-secret-world

Even with sprint (X) turned on, I have to keep pressing W to actually move anywhere. Is there some way to let the character keep running by default, so that all I have to do is course corrections (with A & D) till I get to my destination?

Comment: There is an "auto-walk" keybind. I don't know what the default is because I reconfigured it for my installation of the game. But I'm sure that it exists in the options, I will have a look at the standard configuration as soon as I can access the game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I should have looked into the "Controls"-section of the settings before asking this question (ty @Patrick) -  in the default mapping it's as simple as pressing the middle mouse button, or NumLock on keyboard.